# Not able to save records into db after published to shiny server

Tags: r, database, sqlite, web-applications, shiny

I have published one application on shiny server which basically takes input from users and save into SQLite database in back-end.

My concern is after publishing to shiny server when user is opening the form and saving their input i can't see any record saving in database.However it is working perfectly fine when i try to launch from R-studio without publishing.

I have put database file into shiny folder before publishing,i believe issue might due to the path of the database so is their any specific folder or path on which we suppose to put our database file?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have your own shiny server or are you using shinyapps.io?

Comment: I am using shinyapps.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that shinyapps.io supports write access for sqlite? There is a community post (see https://community.rstudio.com/t/shinyapps-io-and-sqlite-as-persistent-local-data-storage/19361). From this it is clear that shinyapps.io did not support local data storage at that time and there were no concrete plans to implement it. That was one and a half years ago, true, but it may simply be that it is still not be available at this point. That would mean that you can most likely read but not write sqlite.

Hopefully, you find an alternative to store data here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/share-data.html